# Do we know whatever happened to Tosk?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the DS9 episode "Captive Pursuit" Tosk an alien from the Gamma Quadrant comes to DS9 and then escapes with the help of O'Brien.

Do we know what happens to that particular Tosk after he leaves DS9? Please feel free to use EU, novels, or anything else that might provide some insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find Memory Beta useful: there's an [article](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Tosk) on the Tosk.

**That individual Tosk**

It doesn't look like that particular Tosk has anything else, either in canon or out of it. I certainly can't recall a reference to him, and Memory Beta says the same, so unless someone can find a work with him in it, I'll assume there isn't one.

**The Tosk as a species**

There are only two other instances of a Tosk that I can find. One, references in that article, is a book:

> In 2376, a Tosk discovered an Eav'oq vanishing crystal which gave him a vision of Opaka Sulan. He followed the vision to the planet Ee in the Gamma Quadrant where he informed Opaka of the vision. His vision showed him bringing her to the place he found the crystal. (DS9 novel: Rising Son)

The other is a [duty officer in Star Trek online](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Tosk).

Unless someone can contradict me, I'd suggest that there's not much about them because they don't often come in contact with the Federation. Most media in the Star Trek universe is about the Federation, so it makes sense that, even if they're fairly common in the Gamma Quadrant, if they're not in the Alpha/Beta Quadrants, you won't hear much. That, of course, includes that particular Tosk.

Comment: The Tosk (as a race) are mentioned in numerous novels but I can find no reference to *that specific Tosk*.